# Convert OpenGL texture to OpenCV Mat not working

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

I am new at opengl and I try to convert OpenGL texture to OpenCV Mat.
But the screen show nothing.

I init opengl texture with:

```
void InitGlParameter()
{
  GLuint texture;
  if (glIsTexture(texture)) {
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
  }
  glGenTextures(1, &texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, 1280, 720, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

and then I created glWindow and draw something.

```
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
  glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
  glutCreateWindow("SHOW Pic");
```

finally, I used glGetTexImage to convert texture to mat.

```
  cv::Mat img(720, 1280, CV_8UC3);
  glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
  glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, (GLint)(img.rows));
  glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);
  cv::flip(img, img, 0);
```

However, it show nothing in the opencv windows.
Does anyone know where the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of problems with your code.

This reads an uninitialized local variable:

```
  GLuint texture;
  if (glIsTexture(texture)) {
```

This unbinds the texture you just created, therefore it's essentially 'leaked' and you cannot access it afterwards:

```
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Your code doesn't draw anything into the texture, therefore even if everything was right, you shouldn't expect any meaningful data to be returned.

Additionally, `GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH` is the width of the image, so it corresponds to `img.cols` rather than `img.rows`.

To fix the above, you should

- Return the created texture from `InitGlParameter`.
- Draw something meaningful into the texture.
- Bind the texture prior to the `glGetTexImage` call.

Comment: thanks for answer my question, I will try to fix these bug.

Comment: Additionally, what keywords do I need to search if I wanna screenshot that pictures drawn on the window? thanks.

Comment: https://imgur.com/zy23bZr
For example, If I draw a checkerboard in the window, are there any methods that I can get this pic?